# What does it mean that a distribution is integrable?

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I am studying geometric control theory, and I am focusing on the **Frobenius theorem**. I have seen that it gives sufficient and necessary conditions for integrability of a distribution, but I am having troubles understanding well the concept.

The Frobenius theorem states that a distribution is integrable if and only if it is involutive. I have clear the concept of involutivity, but what I have not clear is the concept of integrability.

From the notes of my professor, I have that a distribution $\Delta (x)$ of rank $k$ is integrable if there exist the functions $\lambda_1(x) .... \lambda_{k-n}(x) $ such that:

$\frac{\partial \lambda }{\partial x}\Delta (x)=0$

but what does it mean? I cannot understand clearly the concept of **integrability** of a distribution. Moreover, I don't understand the meaning of the fact that the product of the derivative of $\lambda$ with respect to $x$ with  the distribution gives zero. I know that this implies orthogonality, but what does it mean that these two are orthogonal?

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Integrability of a distribution of rank $k$ can be seen as the extension of the notion of integrability of a vector field.

A vector field is integrable if you can find a curve to which the field is pointwise tangent. The same happens for $k-$distributions but of course you do not have integral curves but *integral submanifolds.*

So the distribution $D$ on $M$ is integrable if, said $D_x$ its element specified on $x\in M$, there exists a submanifold $N\subset M$ such that $T_xN=D_x$ for any $x\in N$.

An example of non-integrable distribution is the one defined over the manifold $M=\mathbb{R}^3$ by linear combinations of the two vector fields:
$$ X = \partial_x + y\partial_z $$
$$ Y = \partial_y$$
in fact
$$[X,Y] = \partial_z $$
which does not belong to $D=\langle X,Y\rangle$.

So by Froebenius theorem you can conclude that $D$ is not integrable, which geometrically means that there is no $2-$dimensional manifold $N$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is pointwise tangent to this distribution.

I suggest you to check Lee book on "Introduction to smooth manifolds" to understand better this concept.

Moreover, it is even possible to relate the concept of integrability of a distribution to a dynamical approach if the manifold $M$ is for example the phase space of a mechanical system.

Comment: I believe you want to give an idea, but, I think you mean a vector field $X$ on a manifold $M$ is integrable if **for each $m\in M$, there is a smooth curve $\gamma:I\rightarrow M$** such that, $X(\gamma(t))=\gamma'(t)$ for each $t\in I$... Unfortunately, I could not find this definition in Lee. I do not remember where I have seen this. Can you please give a reference if you remember where it is mentioned... Google search is not saying any thing about integrable vector field.. It is only saying about integrable distribution..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, you are right. For each initial condition $m\in M$ there is one and only one curve $\gamma\in M$ such that $\gamma(0) = m$ and $\gamma'(0)=X|_m\in T_mM$. This concept of integrability of a vector field does not refer to complete integrability or other aspects, it simply refers to the existence of the integral curves (submanifolds). Maybe if you add something to your comment I can try to answer better